Confirm Selection in tanstack react-table
I have a row selection implemented on my tanstack react table, it is working fine, but there is one thing, i want to add a state that tells me if the user confirms deletion dialog button, and use it on my useEffect to delete my records.
this is a screenshot of my implementation:

i want when he click delete here to toggle the state:

Im using Laravel, spatie query builder, Inertiajs, React, shadcn.
this is the component that handles deletion:

import { useState } from "react";
import { Ingrediant } from "@/types";
import { Table } from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { Button } from "@/Components/ui/button";
import { Trash2 } from "lucide-react";
import { Alert, AlertDescription } from "@/Components/ui/alert";
import {
    AlertDialog,
    AlertDialogAction,
    AlertDialogCancel,
    AlertDialogContent,
    AlertDialogDescription,
    AlertDialogFooter,
    AlertDialogHeader,
    AlertDialogTitle,
    AlertDialogTrigger,
} from "@/Components/ui/alert-dialog";

export default function DataTableRowSelectionToolbar({
    table,
}: {
    table: Table<Ingrediant>;
}) {
    const [isDeleteDialogOpen, setIsDeleteDialogOpen] = useState(false);
    const selectedRowsCount = table.getSelectedRowModel().rows.length;
    const totalRowsCount = table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length;

    const confirmDelete = () => {
        setIsDeleteDialogOpen(false);
       // toggle state here
    };
    return (
        <div className="space-y-2 pt-4 w-full">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                <div className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                    {selectedRowsCount > 0 ? (
                        <>
                            <span className="font-medium text-foreground">
                                {selectedRowsCount}
                            </span>{" "}
                            of{" "}
                            <span className="font-medium text-foreground">
                                {totalRowsCount}
                            </span>{" "}
                            row(s) selected.
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            {" "}
                            <span className="font-medium text-foreground">
                                {totalRowsCount}
                            </span>{" "}
                            rows total.
                        </>
                    )}
                </div>
                {selectedRowsCount > 0 && (
                    <Button
                        variant="ghost"
                        size="sm"
                        onClick={() => table.resetRowSelection()}
                    >
                        Clear selection
                    </Button>
                )}
            </div>

            {selectedRowsCount > 0 && (
                <AlertDialog
                    open={isDeleteDialogOpen}
                    onOpenChange={setIsDeleteDialogOpen}
                >
                    <Alert variant="destructive" className="w-full ">
                        <AlertDialogTrigger asChild>
                            <Button
                                variant="destructive"
                                size="icon"
                                onClick={confirmDelete}
                            >
                                <Trash2 className="h-4 w-4 cursor-pointer" />
                            </Button>
                        </AlertDialogTrigger>
                        <AlertDescription className="inline-flex ml-3">
                            Delete selected rows
                        </AlertDescription>
                    </Alert>
                    <AlertDialogContent>
                        <AlertDialogHeader>
                            <AlertDialogTitle>
                                Are you absolutely sure?
                            </AlertDialogTitle>
                            <AlertDialogDescription>
                                This action cannot be undone. This will
                                permanently delete the {selectedRowsCount}{" "}
                                selected row(s) and remove their data from our
                                servers.
                            </AlertDialogDescription>
                        </AlertDialogHeader>
                        <AlertDialogFooter>
                            <AlertDialogCancel>Cancel</AlertDialogCancel>
                            <AlertDialogAction
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setIsDeleteDialogOpen(false);
                                }}
                            >
                                Delete
                            </AlertDialogAction>
                        </AlertDialogFooter>
                    </AlertDialogContent>
                </AlertDialog>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}


This is where i sent the data to my server:
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("pagination", pagination);
        const queryBuilder = query(route(route().current()!));
        if (isRendered.current) {
            console.log("sorting", sorting);
            const sortQuery = sorting.map(
                (sort) => (sort.desc ? "-" : "") + sort.id
            );
            if (sortQuery.length > 0) queryBuilder.sort(...sortQuery);
            columnFilters.forEach((filter) =>
                queryBuilder.filter(filter.id, filter.value as any)
            );

            const page = pagination.pageIndex + 1;
            console.log(pagination);
            queryBuilder
                .page(page)
                .param("per_page", pagination.pageSize.toString());
            if (queryBuilder.build())
                router.get(queryBuilder.build(), undefined, {
                    preserveState: true,
                    preserveScroll: true,
                    replace: true,
                });
        }
        isRendered.current = true;
    }, [sorting, columnFilters, pagination]);

